# How to disable touch in VideoView?

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am using VideoView for playing videos.And i want to disable any touch events while video is being played. Only buttons of the phone should work.
I have already tried following different ways.here vv is my VideoView.

```
      vv.setClickable(false);

      vv.onTouchEvent(null);

      vv.setEnabled(false);
```

Any kind of help is appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this...

```
vv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // do nothing here......
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: you can also try onClick() as well... as above

Comment: It is working now with vv.setOnTouchListener(...... solution. previosly it was not working because of some other code. Thanks @MAC